# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel

I have created an HTML template to WordPress theme which has 3 carousels.  In localhost, all the carousel works fine But in the live server, it does not work properly. Even carousels are not showing.
When I check in the console to find out the problem I got these errors.
How can solve these errors??
[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQUQS.png)

Comment: where is your javascript code ?

Comment: Have you seen the screenshot?

Comment: yes thats not code... either way, your code should not be in a screenshot